# Controlling spring scheduled tasks at run time

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a set of services written in Java using spring framework. Some of the services have scheduled tasks(using spring's `@Scheduled` annotation) to do some house keeping stuff (generating processed data, data cleanup etc.). Because of these schedule tasks, I cannot run multiple instances of the services since all instances are picking up the same task and it is executed multiple times, resulting in repeated/corrupted data. To resolve this, I want to check at time of execution of the task and allow the execution only on one instance. How can I do it?
Is there a better approach to the problem?

Comment: Do you run your app on a cloud? What does it mean to have multiple instances of the services?

Comment: @MarekRaszewski.. Yes, its a web service which is hosted in AWS ec2 instances.

Comment: I am currently developing on Google Cloud and I resolved such a problem by using cron jobs. Is in AWS such a functionality? If it is, just set up a cron that will call your service instead of doing this on the instance level.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for this problem.

You can make use of [Shedlock](https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring) a Spring Boot library that works with locks in a database.

Or you can solve it by making use of on Queue as follows:

- move all your scheduled tasks to an apart (small) service, which's purpose will be firing events / messages to a Queue so that other services can consume these events / messages.
- your services should listen to the events and execute the tasks.

Now you can scale your services without any problems. And since the messages are sent into a Queue only 1 service will consume the message.

You can also achieve the same with Kafka-like messagebrokers, but here you have to make sure that your service belongs to a consumer-group so that the messages get loadbalanced between the services.

Another advantage of this solution is that you can easily shutdown all the cronjobs by just killing the scheduler-service without impacting your services/applications.